"Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.CentralModelMissingException" when retrieving Revit model from ACC using APS
I'm working on an APS (Autodesk Platform Services) plugin to access a Revit file stored on ACC. I've successfully obtained the project GUID and model GUID but encounter the "CentralModelMissingException" when trying to open the model.
C# code Snippet:
var cloudModelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(inputParams.Region, inputParams.ProjectGuid, inputParams.ModelGuid);
Document doc = rvtApp.OpenDocumentFile(cloudModelPath, new OpenOptions()); 

Error Message:

Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.CentralModelMissingException: The central
model is missing.
at Autodesk.Revit.DB.ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(String
region, Guid projectGuid, Guid modelGuid)

Details:
I used the following API endpoint to fetch project and model GUIDs:

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.ab6853f0-5a67-4906-bcf8-c78daecc38be/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:2_RgTcCLSvWwx7ct1TETkA/versions

and got following response:
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.ab6853f0-5a67-4906-bcf8-c78daecc38be/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:2_RgTcCLSvWwx7ct1TETkA/versions"
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.2_RgTcCLSvWwx7ct1TETkA?version=2",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "001_ US method_MODEL FOR TESTING.rvt",
                "displayName": "001_ US method_MODEL FOR TESTING.rvt",
                "createTime": "2024-04-30T07:52:41.0000000Z",
                "createUserId": "JP3VNYE6UKU8",
                "createUserName": "SWAPP SU",
                "lastModifiedTime": "2024-04-30T07:55:03.0000000Z",
                "lastModifiedUserId": "JP3VNYE6UKU8",
                "lastModifiedUserName": "SWAPP SU",
                "versionNumber": 2,
                "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
                "storageSize": 41287680,
                "fileType": "rvt",
                "extension": {
                    "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
                    "version": "1.3.1",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.3.1"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "modelVersion": 17,
                        "isCompositeDesign": false,
                        "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
                        "revitProjectVersion": 2023,
                        "projectGuid": "3fa3b423-3b58-48b8-bccf-c2e32babf431",
                        "publishType": "WithLinks",
                        "originalItemUrn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:2_RgTcCLSvWwx7ct1TETkA",
                        "modelType": "multiuser",
                        "latestEpisodeGuid": "1d1873fc-cd7b-4079-92ab-1c28152c02a0",
                        "modelGuid": "5a015771-c579-42b2-a87c-77cd68ff0b29",
                        "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                        "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
                        "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
                        "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
                        "revisionDisplayLabel": "2",
                        "sourceFileName": "001_ US method_MODEL FOR TESTING.rvt",
                        "conformingStatus": "NONE"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {...},
            "relationships": {...}
        },
        {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.2_RgTcCLSvWwx7ct1TETkA?version=1",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "001_ US method_MODEL FOR TESTING.rvt",
                "displayName": "001_ US method_MODEL FOR TESTING.rvt",
                "createTime": "2024-04-30T07:52:00.0000000Z",
                "createUserId": "JP3VNYE6UKU8",
                "createUserName": "SWAPP SU",
                "lastModifiedTime": "2024-04-30T07:52:05.0000000Z",
                "lastModifiedUserId": "JP3VNYE6UKU8",
                "lastModifiedUserName": "SWAPP SU",
                "versionNumber": 1,
                "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
                "extension": {
                    "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
                    "version": "1.1.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.1.0"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "modelVersion": 17,
                        "projectGuid": "3fa3b423-3b58-48b8-bccf-c2e32babf431",
                        "modelType": "multiuser",
                        "latestEpisodeGuid": "1d1873fc-cd7b-4079-92ab-1c28152c02a0",
                        "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
                        "modelGuid": "5a015771-c579-42b2-a87c-77cd68ff0b29",
                        "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                        "extractionState": "SKIPPED",
                        "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
                        "revisionDisplayLabel": "1",
                        "sourceFileName": "001_ US method_MODEL FOR TESTING.rvt",
                        "conformingStatus": "NONE"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {...},
            "relationships": {...}
        }
    ]
}

The API response provided a project GUID of 3fa3b423-3b58-48b8-bccf-c2e32babf431, which seems different from the project ID I initially used.
Questions:
Project ID vs. Project GUID: What's the difference between these two identifiers, and which one should I use in conjunction with ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath?
Troubleshooting "CentralModelMissingException":

What are common reasons why the central model might be missing?
How can I verify the Revit model's status and worksharing configuration on ACC?
Pre-Access Verification: Is there a way to "ping" the ACC model using an API call to ensure it's accessible before attempting to open it in Revit?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
I have tried to run the following code from Revit itself
string Region = "US";
System.Guid ModelGuid = new System.Guid("5a015771-c579-42b2-a87c-77cd68ff0b29");
System.Guid ProjectGuid = new System.Guid("3fa3b423-3b58-48b8-bccf-c2e32babf431");
ModelPath cloudModelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(Region, ProjectGuid, ModelGuid);
TransactionUtils.ForceCloseTransaction();
OpenOptions options = new OpenOptions();
options.DetachFromCentralOption = DetachFromCentralOption.DetachAndDiscardWorksets;
var doc1 = uiApplication.OpenAndActivateDocument(cloudModelPath, options, true);

and got another error:

Warning DynamicCodeUtils: InvalidOperationException - This Document is
not a workshared document.

But the document is workshared, I have checked it from revit web view.
And running the GetPublishJob api, I receive following response:
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "766dce34-efc9-4895-8d04-6dbbbf5b162c",
            "status": "403",
            "code": "C4R",
            "detail": "Failed to get publish model job"
        }
    ]
}


To answer your questions:
- Project ID vs. Project GUID: What's the difference between these two identifiers, and which one should I use in conjunction with ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath?
Answer: To open the Revit Cloud Model, you need the GUID of Project and Model as you find at attributes.extension.data, the project id is just the ACC project, not related to the Revit Cloud Model.
- What are common reasons why the central model might be missing?
Answer: can you make sure the Region you provided for the method ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath() is correct? are you trying to open a RCM from EU region? You need to use the correct region to get the RCM.
- How can I verify the Revit model's status and worksharing configuration on ACC?
Answer: To verify if the RCM is already be pulished to latest, you can try with https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/GetPublishModelJob/ .
- Pre-Access Verification: Is there a way to "ping" the ACC model using an API call to ensure it's accessible before attempting to open it in Revit?
Answer: There is not such a "ping" method AFAIK, maybe you can use the GetPublishModelJob as I mentioned above to check? But I would suggest to try to get the model path by ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(), you will get the exception if the model can not be found.

Have tried both regions US and EU. For US I'm getting an error "The central model is missing", for EU: "The central server could not be reached".

sorry for not seeing your comments in time, which region are your Revit models located in? Do you still need help on this?
